# prioritized experience replay (PER)

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have a question about prioritized experience replay (PER) proposed as a an improvement for DQN [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05952). As it has been mentioned there,
[image]
[image]

here to take k samples, we break the interval of (0, sum of priorities) into k sub-intervals and choose a number uniformly at random from each sub-interval. My question is that why we are doing this? Why don't we just choose k numbers each uniformly at random from the original interval?

In this paper, it says that if the prioritization exponent is 0, that is all samples have the priority of 1, then PER is the same as uniform sampling. But, because of dividing the interval to sub-interval, it seems to me it is not the same.

Any idea? As a simple example assume the memory size is 5 and all the priorities are 1. Now, if we want to take 5 samples, the above method, choose each sample exactly once. However, if we take samples from (0,5), it is possible to choose one sample more than once and never choose one other sample. It seems to me that in the above method, the sampling is not idd anymore.